# Combine FlatMap duplicates for every new successful upstream

Tags: swift, combine

In my Combine pipeline, I'm trying to prevent the upstream from terminating by using `flatMap` to catch the error outside of the original publisher:

```
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let cancellable = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .default)
    .autoconnect()
    .flatMap { _ in
        Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .default)
            .autoconnect()
            .tryMap { value throws -> String? in
                return "\(Date())"
            }
            .catch { _ in
                Just(nil)
            }
            .filter { $0 != nil }
    }
    .sink { _ in
        print("complete")
        PlaygroundPage.current.finishExecution()
    } receiveValue: {
        print("sink: \(String(describing: $0))")
    }
```

Although this never terminates the upstream publisher when an error is replaced with a `nil`, it's duplicating every upstream event for some reason. The above code will result as:

```
sink: Optional("2021-01-16 06:49:58 +0000")
sink: Optional("2021-01-16 06:49:59 +0000")
sink: Optional("2021-01-16 06:49:59 +0000")
sink: Optional("2021-01-16 06:50:00 +0000")
sink: Optional("2021-01-16 06:50:00 +0000")
sink: Optional("2021-01-16 06:50:00 +0000")
sink: Optional("2021-01-16 06:50:01 +0000")
sink: Optional("2021-01-16 06:50:01 +0000")
sink: Optional("2021-01-16 06:50:01 +0000")
sink: Optional("2021-01-16 06:50:01 +0000")
sink: Optional("2021-01-16 06:50:02 +0000")
sink: Optional("2021-01-16 06:50:02 +0000")
sink: Optional("2021-01-16 06:50:02 +0000")
sink: Optional("2021-01-16 06:50:02 +0000")
sink: Optional("2021-01-16 06:50:02 +0000")
sink: Optional("2021-01-16 06:50:03 +0000")
sink: Optional("2021-01-16 06:50:03 +0000")
sink: Optional("2021-01-16 06:50:03 +0000")
sink: Optional("2021-01-16 06:50:03 +0000")
sink: Optional("2021-01-16 06:50:03 +0000")
sink: Optional("2021-01-16 06:50:03 +0000")
```

On the first event, output is just once. Second upstream event, it's twice. Third upstream result in three outputs and so on.

It seems like `flatMap` creates a new publisher every upstream event and stays alive. How do I cancel the previous flatMaps and always get one value, or is there a better way to do this? I don't want past upstream events to stay alive, I only care of the one value not old ones. I'd want to end up with something like:

```
sink: Optional("2021-01-16 06:49:58 +0000")
sink: Optional("2021-01-16 06:49:59 +0000")
sink: Optional("2021-01-16 06:50:00 +0000")
sink: Optional("2021-01-16 06:50:01 +0000")
sink: Optional("2021-01-16 06:50:02 +0000")
sink: Optional("2021-01-16 06:50:03 +0000")
sink: Optional("2021-01-16 06:50:03 +0000")
```

Comment: I don't understand why you are using `flatMap` in the first place. Can't you just use one single `Timer` publisher? You said something about "prevent the upstream from terminating by using flatMap to catch the error outside of the original publisher", but the timer example doesn't illustrate that...

Comment: It’s a basic example trying to capture a more complex scenario. Imagine the inner timer can randomly fail and produce an error. The inner timer in my real world case is a request GPS location call.

Comment: I think `flatMap(maxPublishers: .max(1))` is what I'm after

Comment: actually seems like max publisher only keeps the original first one alive and doesn't accept new signals for subsequent publishers from the upstream :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FlatMap`'s closure returns a publisher for every upstream value. That returned publisher can be emitting multiple values. So, in your example, every second a `FlatMap` returns a new Timer publisher that keeps publishing values every second.

Instead, use the `Just` publisher to emit each upstream value and

```
Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .default)
    .autoconnect()
    .flatMap { value in
        Just(value)
            .tryMap { value throws -> String? in
                return "\(Date())"
            }
            .catch { _ in
                Just(nil)
            }
            .filter { $0 != nil }
    }
```

---

It might be simpler for your example to use `compactMap` and use `try?` for throwing calls, instead of the `flatMap` approach:

```
Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .default)
    .autoconnect()
    .compactMap { value in
        try? someThrowingFunction(value)
    }
```

Comment: In my real case, my inner timer is a GPS location request so it needs to be a live publisher. Is there a way to have the flatMap publisher to only subscribe to the last upstream event? its not making sense to me why the upstream's previous values are being sent instead of just the last one.

Comment: @TruMan1, your example is then overly simplified and does not represent well the problem you're trying to solve. For example, why do you have an upstream `Timer` publisher? Maybe what you need is `.retry`? It's all a guess since your example is too simplified

Comment: Also, what do you mean by not making sense - that's how `FlatMap` was designed to work - it produces a publisher per upstream value. That publisher will publish however many values it will.

Comment: I think what I'm not getting is a brand new flatMap publisher is being created whenever the it fires but all previous flatMap publishers are still alive too. So I'm creating a whole bunch of new publishers. I think it will click soon I feel it. I'll accept the answer because it does help my over simplistic example. Thank you for shedding light on any things for me!

Comment: Here's another angle on my issue, hopefully zeroing in on what I'm missing. Thanks again for the help! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65755015/how-to-complete-publisher-after-one-event-only

Comment: @TruMan1, there's only one `FlatMap` publisher. But it produces multiple "inner" publishers and merges their outputs. You can restrict it to have only a certain maximum concurrent number of inner publishers with `.flatMap(maxPublishers: .max(1))`

Comment: That’s what I tried but it seems the max publisher only accepts the first upstream event. Imagine the upstream publisher is a location authorization listener which can change back and forth. I’d care about the last authorization value, not the initial one.